# Do we need open the middleware link in browser?

Tags: mysql, web, heroku, server

I don't understand why i don't need to run middleware server on our browser? For my final project, it has a front end, middleware, and back end. The front end is React, the middleware is java server, and the back end is MySQL. When I push the whole project to Heroku, I only need to push the front end and the middleware to Heroku. The back end is an add-on remote database, which is provided by Heroku itself. I choose ClearDB for example. My understanding is that the remote database is running by itself on the cloud. It’s never down unless I disable it, and It always waits for queries from my java server. I always thought I need to open the Heroku link of the java server, and then I could open the Heroku link of the front end. When I try to communicate data from the front end to the database, it is transmitted via middleware. That’s why I need the java server running online. It’s just like what we do locally. To let the front end send data to the database, we need to run the server. However, after I push the project to Heroku, I found I didn’t need to open the Heroku link of java server to run the server. Instead, I only need to open the font-end link, and I could register or change profiles without problems. That confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

leaving any rdms(database) open to the Internet, to access it directly invites hackers and Script kiddies to enter the database and grab what they can.

That is why we always answer to developers like Android to not access the database directly. but to use a serverside based web Middleware like php, python django .....

So that the credentials for the rdms can be hidden on the server and not in the app or frontend where anybody can reach them.

So that is 1 good reason, why the rdms are usually a backend service and in a sense exchangeble and you can combine them.

Your idea that java and database are on the same level, is in my opinion wrong, java is only middleware and as such replaceable. Ok front and back end are also replaceable.

Heroku as it self is no middleware, it is a Backend platform on that you can build your middleware and it is actually in the same level as the database.

It is like AWS, Google, Microsoft, Baidu, ALibaba.

They offer also Middleware as a service.

In my eyes they are all Backend level.